# Get the value of automatic interval for LinearAxis on Chart (System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, charts

I have a .NET project working with System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting.

When creating a new LinearAxis, I leave out the Interval so that it is computed automatically, like this:

```
new LinearAxis()
{
    Title = "My Data",
    ShowGridLines = true,
    Orientation = AxisOrientation.Y,
    Maximum = 100
}
```

I want to add a secondary Y axis. However, to make the tick marks on both axes line up, I need to explicitly set the Interval of my second Y axis based on the Interval of my first Y axis.

The problem is, the Interval of my first Y axis is computed automatically, and returns Null. The ActualInterval returns 0.

How can I obtain the Interval value for a LinearAxis created with an automatic Interval, like the above code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve that by using **Binding**, as below:

```
    <chartingToolkit:Chart Margin="0" Title="Chart Title">
        <chartingToolkit:Chart.Axes>
            <chartingToolkit:LinearAxis x:Name="ax1" 
                                        Orientation="Y" 
                                        ShowGridLines="True" 
                                        Title="First Axis"
                                        Minimum="0"
                                        />
            <chartingToolkit:LinearAxis x:Name="ax2" 
                                        Orientation="Y" 
                                        ShowGridLines="True" 
                                        Title="Second Axis"
                                        Interval="{Binding ElementName=ax1, Path=ActualInterval}" 
                                        Maximum="{Binding ElementName=ax1, Path=ActualMaximum}" 
                                        />
        </chartingToolkit:Chart.Axes>
        <chartingToolkit:ColumnSeries DependentValuePath="Y" IndependentValuePath="X" ItemsSource="{Binding}"/>
    </chartingToolkit:Chart>
```

[image]

**EDIT:** This is the code-behind equivalent for the previous XAML:

```
    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        chart1 = new Chart();

        LinearAxis ax1 = new LinearAxis
        {
            Title = "First Axis",
            ShowGridLines = true,
            Orientation = AxisOrientation.Y,
            Minimum = 0
        };

        Binding b1 = new Binding();
        b1.Source = ax1;
        b1.Path = new PropertyPath("ActualInterval");

        Binding b2 = new Binding();
        b2.Source = ax1;
        b2.Path = new PropertyPath("ActualMaximum");

        LinearAxis ax2 = new LinearAxis
        {
            Title = "Second Axis",
            ShowGridLines = true,
            Orientation = AxisOrientation.Y
        };

        ax2.SetBinding(LinearAxis.IntervalProperty, b1);
        ax2.SetBinding(LinearAxis.MaximumProperty, b2);

        chart1.Axes.Add(ax1);
        chart1.Axes.Add(ax2);

        PointCollection pc = new PointCollection();
        pc.Add(new Point { X = 1, Y = 10 });
        pc.Add(new Point { X = 2, Y = 20 });
        pc.Add(new Point { X = 3, Y = 30 });
        pc.Add(new Point { X = 4, Y = 40 });

        ColumnSeries series = new ColumnSeries();
        series.ItemsSource = pc;
        series.DependentValuePath = "Y";
        series.IndependentValuePath = "X";

        chart1.Series.Add(series);
        AddChild(chart1);
    }
```

Comment: This is a good answer. In my case, I'm not using binding, but rather creating a chart in memory and then saving it as an image, for export as PDF, Word, etc. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Please see my **EDIT**.